# Vertically centering of text in multirow in table when using \cmidrule

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment

Consider the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\DeclareSIUnit[mode = text]\kroner{kr.}

\usepackage{booktabs,multirow}
\newcommand*\mr[2]{\multirow{#1}{*}{#2}}
\newcommand*\mc[2]{\multicolumn{#1}{c}{#2}}
\newcommand*\specialcell[2][c]{%
  \begin{tabular}[#1]{@{}c@{}}#2\end{tabular}}


\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{
  l
  S[table-format = 3]
  S[table-format = 2.2]
}
 \toprule
    \mr{2}{\specialcell{Dansk\\ honning}}
  & \mc{2}{$1$~b{\ae}ger}       \\
    \cmidrule{2-3}               
  & \mc{1}{Masse~(\si{\g})}
  & \mc{1}{Pris~(\si{\kroner})} \\
 \midrule
    Almindelig
  & 450 & 14.95 \\
 \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

How do I vertically center `Dansk honning` relativt to the first two lines?

I've come to the conclusion that the problem occurs because some space is added around `\cmidrule`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can adjust the placement of the multirow content by approximately -(\aboverulesep + \belowrulesep)/2. `-0.4ex` seems to be OK. In addition, I replaced your `\multirow{2}{*}{\specialcell{…}}` command with the `\multirowcell` command from [`makecell`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/makecell), which does the same thing, and can be further customised (font, horizontal and vertical alignment, ect.):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\DeclareSIUnit[mode = text]\kroner{kr.}

\usepackage{booktabs,multirow}
\newcommand*\mc[2]{\multicolumn{#1}{c}{#2}}
\usepackage{makecell}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{
  l
  S[table-format = 3]
  S[table-format = 2.2]
}
 \toprule
    \multirowcell{2}[-0.4ex]{Dansk\\honning}
  & \mc{2}{$1$~b{\ae}ger} \\
    \cmidrule{2-3}
  & \mc{1}{Masse~(\si{\g})}
  & \mc{1}{Pris~(\si{\kroner})} \\
 \midrule
    Almindelig
  & 450 & 14.95 \\
 \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You say that the adjustment should be approximately -(\aboverulesep + \belowrulesep)/2 but is the thickness of the rule itself then taken into account?

Comment: You're right, I didn't take it into account, but I don't think you'll see the difference: half the default `\cmidrulewidth` will be `0.015em`. Moreover the adjustment might vary according to ascenders, descenders, mixed lowercase and uppercase letters or not. The adjustment required by the eye is not necessarily *exactly* the geometric midpoint between the two lines.

Comment: Good point; I'll leave it at `-0.4ex`.