# multirow (2) vertical center text

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment

MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{@{}l|llll@{}}
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{Test}} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{A} \\ \cmidrule(l){2-5} 
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}                      & 1   & 2   & 3   & 4   \\ \midrule
                                           &     &     &     &     \\
                                           &     &     &     &     \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Saw [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/71315), [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/334005). Somewhere, I have to use `makecell` or `m`, but not able to grasp. Any help in making the "Test" vertically align.

Comment: Since rules from `booktabs` package add some vertical white space above and below them, hence the incompatibility with vertical lines (please keep that in mind) and the gaps around the intersections, `\multirow{2}` will not result in the expected output. You could try with something like `\multirow{2.4}` or other non-integer values.

Comment: Side note on your MWE: Compiling results in a bunch of error messages since you can't have a float like `table` inside of the `standalone` class. Either keep the `table` and switch to `article` or a different standard class or stick with `standalone` and remove the `table`.

Comment: Depending on the actual contents of your table, it might be better to not vertically center the contents, but leave them top aligned as they usually are. If you with to keep the booktabs rules, stay away from vertical lines entirely.

Comment: See also: [Proper centering with cmidrule and multi- row and column](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/156219/134144), [Vertical alignment using multirow and booktabs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/66564/134144) and [Vertically centering of text in multirow in table when using \cmidrule](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/218884/134144) for more related questions that address vertically centered contents of `\multirow` next to a `\cmidrule`.

Comment: @leandriis, Thanks for the link, 1st link indeed solved my problem. changed `\multirow{2}{*}{Test}` to `\multirow{2}[3]{*}{Test}`. However, did not understand what `[N]` does. Can you explain it?

Answer (score 4):

Avoid verticals for a better impact and troubles with gaps

The `\multirow` option can be changed to decimal values for finer up-down adjustment/centering -- here changed to value of 2.4

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[]
\begin{tabular}{@{}lllll@{}}                                      \toprule                    
\multirow{2.4}{*}{Test}         & \multicolumn{4}{c}{A}                 \\ \cmidrule(l){2-5}   
                                & 1                     & 2   & 3   & 4 \\ \midrule
                                & X                     & Y   & Z   & A \\
                                & P                     & Q   & R   & S \\ \bottomrule 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is what you can do with `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix` (with the latest version: 5.4 of 2020-10-06).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{@{}l|llll@{}}
\toprule
\Block{2-1}{Test} & \Block{1-4}{A} \\ \cmidrule(l){2-5} 
                  & 1   & 2   & 3   & 4   \\ \midrule
                  &     &     &     &     \\
                  &     &     &     &     \\ \bottomrule
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

- In `{NiceTabular}`, you use `\Block` to merge cells both vertically and horizontally.
- The content of the block is composed at the mathemtatical center of the rectangle of the merged cells (not as with `\multirow`).
- The vertical rules are not broken and thus, are compatible with `booktabs` (but you must be aware that the use of vertical rules is not at all in the spirit of `booktabs`).
- You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes).

[image: Ouput of the above code]

Comment: Good to know about `nicematrix`, thanks.